# Decode Base64 content from a MimeMultipart

Tags: java, base64, mime, jakarta-mail

I have a Base64 file into one part of my `MimeMessage`.
I put it like this

```
DataSource source = new FileDataSource(new File("base64Test.bin"));
bodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
```

Then, I want to decode it using the method `BASE64DecoderStream.decode`

```
String base64 = (String)bodyPart.getContent();
byte [] base64Decoder = BASE64DecoderStream.decode(base64.getBytes());
```

The problem with that is that I have always an `ArrayOutOfboundexception` when I use this method.

Any advice in order to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try out Apache Commons' [Base64 class](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#decodeBase64(java.lang.String)) to decode it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, a Base64DecoderStream takes an InputStream, not a byte array.  At a minimum, you need to change the decoding like so:

```
ByteArrayInputStream contentStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(base64Content.getBytes());
BASE64DecoderStream decodeStream = new BASE64DecoderStream(contentStream);
int decodedByte
while ((decodedByte = read()) != -1) {
   // handled decoded bytes
}
```

Perhaps autoboxing is trying to help you out, and some "intermediate" array creation is fouling the works.  Or, maybe your message is just large enough that an array can't be created big enough.  Or maybe you have two threads calling the static offering which is messing up internal shared buffers.

Comment: Thanks a lot but the decode method of BASE64DecoderStream support a byte array type , not a ByteArrayInputStream , and i have test this : public byte[] read(ByteArrayInputStream bais) {
     byte[] array = new byte[bais.available()];
     bais.read(array);

     return array;
}
but doesn ' t work beacause the inputStream returned is a Sharedbytearrayinputstream  ! How to decode this ? Thanks a lot

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for your response !
After various test , indeed , my messages received are too big for my byteArray
I use instead the Sharedbytearrayinputstream and now it works perfectly.

Thanks a lot Edwin Buck !

Comment: @user799698, Glad to have helped, good luck with the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

I read the BASE64DecoderStream like this:

```java
DataHandler handler = bodyPart.getDataHandler();
System.out.println("attachment name : " + handler.getName());
                    
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(handler.getName()));
handler.writeTo(fos);
```

this OutPutStream is having data which has been written to file.